# SSJS - left shift operator (<<) and 2's Complement different behaviour than in JS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I hope someone has some experience with `left shift (<<)` and `2's Complement` in `SSJS` and can help me to confirm my assumption and suggest a better approach for that problem.

### Assumption

1. SSJS is not using 2's Complement resulting in `Arithmetic operation overflow` when dealing with negative numbers.
2. SSJS left shift operator `<<` is using the logical approach of `x * ( 2 ** y )` irrespectively of a 32 bit size. This results in a larger number as there are no excess bits and it will continue to shift with zeros from the right.

### Question

1. How can I overcome the missing 2's Complement in SSJS?
2. Is there a way to limit the size of the shift to 32 bit in SSJS?
3. My sample code below works but I am interested if there is a better solution.

### Deep dive

I believe I understand how shifting bits in a signed 32 bit integer works but there are still a few grey areas so please be gentle if anything below is not accurate.

> Shifting the current bits to the left by the specific number of bits. Excess bits shifted off to the left are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the right.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");
   
    var i = 1073741824,
        i_bit = i.toString(2); // 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    
    // shifting i by 1 bit to the left
    var i_shifted = (i << 1); // 2147483648
        i_shifted_bit = i_shifted.toString(2); // 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
    
    Write(i+'<br/>');
    Write(i_bit+'<br/>');
    Write(i_shifted+'<br/>');
    Write(i_shifted_bit+'<br/>');
</script>
```

Here is the first difference between SSJS and JS. JS is using 2's Complement and uses the last position as a negative indicator. This seems to be different in SSJS as it does not allow negative numbers for shifting at all.

```
SSJS:
 268435456 |   16777216 |   1048576 | 65536 | 4096 |  256 |   16 |    1 (32 bit)
      1... |       0... |      0... |  0... | 0... | 0... | 0... | ...0 = 268435456

JS Shifting with 2's Complement is using the highest bit as -:
-268435456 |   16777216 |   1048576 | 65536 | 4096 |  256 |   16 |    1 (32 bit)
      1... |       0... |      0... |  0... | 0... | 0... | 0... | ...0 = -268435456
```

If you try `-1 << 1` in JS your result will be `-2`.
In SSJS this throws an `Arithmetic operation overflow` Error.

---

The other difference is that the left shift operator (`<<`) yields different results in SSJS than in JS. I assume it is just a quick implementation of the algorithm `x * ( 2 ** y )`. This results that the excess bits are not dropped but the number is extended beyond the 32 bit integer.

This will not allow me to convert the integer into a binary string as it exceed the allowance of Uint32.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");
   
    var i = 1073741824,
        i_bit = i.toString(2); // 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    
    // shifting i by 1 bit to the left
    var i_shifted = (i << 2) // 4294967296
        // System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32
        // i_shifted_bit = i_shifted.toString(2); // 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
    
    Write(i+'<br/>');
    Write(i_bit+'<br/>');
    Write(i_shifted+'<br/>');
    Write(i_shifted_bit+'<br/>');
</script>
```

The expected value is `0` and not `4294967296` as the leading `01` is shifted out of the 32 bit window as we define a left shift of 2.

### My take  to solve this

As mentioned above, I was wondering if there is a better way of solving this in SSJS. Here is my code:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");
 
    try {

       function leftShift(a,b) { 
            var d = a<<b,
                r = [],
                i = 0,
                n = (d<0)?true:false;

            d = (n)?d*-1:d
            if ( d == 0) {
              return 0;
            }


            // Decimal integers to binary: Algorithm
            // Step 1. Divide the integer by 2, while noting the quotient and remainder.
            // Step 2. Then, divide the quotient again by 2, and record the 3rd quotient and remainder.
            // Step 3. Like this, keep dividing each successive quotient by 2 until you get a quotient of zero.
            // Step 4. After this, just write all the remainders in reverse order to get the binary representation of the integer.
            while (d !== 0) {
                r[i++] = (d % 2); // store remainder
                d = Math.floor(d/2); // store quotient
            }

            // if it exceed 32 drop the overflow
            if (r.length > 32) {
                r = r.slice(0,32)
            }

            // reverse the binary array join each element and parseInt
            r = parseInt(r.reverse().join(''), 2);

            return (n)?-1*r:r;
        }


        Write(leftShift(1073741824,1)+'<br/>'); // -2147483648
        Write(leftShift(1073741824,2)+'<br/>'); // 0
        Write(leftShift(5,3)+'<br/>'); // 20
        Write(leftShift(-1,1)+'<br/>'); // -2

    } catch(e) {
        Write(e)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What kind SFMC solution involves fiddling with bits?

Comment: Involves SHA256 but will share when finished as usual

Answer (score 0):

The code from my question had many flaws and it took me a while to get a better working version. The following code has been tested against 20 000 iterations of different positive and negative shifts.

There is a possability that it can yield a different result and I am keen to see if anyone has a better / simpler solution to enable left shift in SSJS with 2s Complement and negative numbers.

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");

    var util = {};

    util.findTwoscomplement = function(str) {
        var n = str.length;

        // Traverse the string to get first '1' from the last of string
        var i;
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (str.charAt(i) == '1')
                break;

        // If there exists no '1' concat 1 at the starting of string
        if (i == -1)
            return "1" + str;

        // Continue traversal after the position of first '1'
        for (k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            // Just flip the values
            if (str.charAt(k) == '1')
                str = str.substring(0, k) + "0" + str.substring(k + 1, str.length);
            else
                str = str.substring(0, k) + "1" + str.substring(k + 1, str.length);
        }

        // return the modified string
        return str.toString();
    }

    util.decimalToBinary = function(d) {
        var i = 0,
            r = [], // store the result
            n = (d < 0) ? true : false; // if negative we use ceil otherwise floor for compute

        // Decimal integers to binary: Algorithm
        // Step 1. Divide the integer by 2, while noting the quotient and remainder.
        // Step 2. Then, divide the quotient again by 2, and record the 3rd quotient and remainder.
        // Step 3. Like this, keep dividing each successive quotient by 2 until you get a quotient of zero.
        // Step 4. After this, just write all the remainders in reverse order to get the binary representation of the integer.
        while (d !== 0) {
            r[i++] = (n) ? -1 * (d % 2) : (d % 2); // store remainder
            d = (n) ? Math.ceil(d / 2) : Math.floor(d / 2); // store quotient
        }

        // reverse to get the actual binary value
        r = r.reverse().join('');

        // if decimal was positive we can just pad an return otherwise convert to 2s complement
        if (!n) {
            return r.padStart(32, '0');
        } else {
            return util.findTwoscomplement(r).padStart(32, '1');
        }
    }

    util.binaryToDecimal = function(b) {
        var a = Array.from(b),
            r = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            var v = Number(a[i]) * Math.pow(2, (31 - i))
            r = (i == 0) ? r - v : r + v;
        }
        return r;
    };

    util.leftShift = function(a, b) {
        // only shift a maximum of 32 bits
        var b = b % 32;

        // convert a to binary
        a = util.decimalToBinary(a);

        // pad from the right with the length of b
        a = a.padEnd((b + a.length), '0');

        // only take the last 32 bits
        a = a.substr(a.length - 32, a.length);

        // convert binary to decimal with 2s complement
        return util.binaryToDecimal(a);
    };




    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////           //////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////// POLYFILLS ////////////////////////////// 
    //////////////////////////////           //////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // ECMAScript (ECMA-262)
    Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
        return typeof value === 'number' &&
            isFinite(value) &&
            Math.floor(value) === value;
    };

    // Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 6, 22.1.2.1
    if (!Array.from) {
        Array.from = (function() {
            var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
            var isCallable = function(fn) {
                return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
            };
            var toInteger = function(value) {
                var number = Number(value);
                if (isNaN(number)) { return 0; }
                if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number)) { return number; }
                return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
            };
            var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
            var toLength = function(value) {
                var len = toInteger(value);
                return Math.min(Math.max(len, 0), maxSafeInteger);
            };

            // The length property of the from method is 1.
            return function from(arrayLike /*, mapFn, thisArg */ ) {
                // 1. Let C be the this value.
                var C = this;

                // 2. Let items be ToObject(arrayLike).
                var items = arrayLike;

                // 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(items).
                if (arrayLike == null) {
                    throw new TypeError('Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined');
                }

                // 4. If mapfn is undefined, then let mapping be false.
                var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
                var T;
                if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
                    // 5. else
                    // 5. a If IsCallable(mapfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
                    if (!isCallable(mapFn)) {
                        throw new TypeError('Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function');
                    }

                    // 5. b. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
                    if (arguments.length > 2) {
                        T = arguments[2];
                    }
                }

                // 10. Let lenValue be Get(items, "length").
                // 11. Let len be ToLength(lenValue).
                var len = toLength(items.length);

                // 13. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
                // 13. a. Let A be the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method 
                // of C with an argument list containing the single item len.
                // 14. a. Else, Let A be ArrayCreate(len).
                var A = isCallable(C) ? new C(len) : new Array(len);

                // 16. Let k be 0.
                var k = 0;
                // 17. Repeat, while k < len… (also steps a - h)
                var kValue;
                while (k < len) {
                    kValue = items[k];
                    if (mapFn) {
                        A[k] = typeof T === 'undefined' ? mapFn(kValue, k) : mapFn.call(T, kValue, k);
                    } else {
                        A[k] = kValue;
                    }
                    k += 1;
                }
                // 18. Let putStatus be Put(A, "length", len, true).
                A.length = len;
                // 20. Return A.
                return A;
            };
        }());
    }
    if (!String.prototype.substr) {
        String.prototype.substr = function(a, b) {
            var s = (!Number.isInteger(a)) ? 0 : a,
                l = (typeof b == 'undefined') ? null : (s > 0 && b > 0) ? s + b : b;
            if (s < 0) {
                s = this.length + a;
                l = (l < 0) ? 0 : s + l;
            }
            return (typeof b == 'undefined' && b != 0 && Number.isInteger(a)) ? this.substring(s) : (l <= 0 || !Number.isInteger(l)) ? "" : this.substring(s, l);
        };
    }

    /**
     * String.repeat()
     * version 0.0.0
     */
    if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
        Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'repeat', {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: function(count) {
                if (this == null) {
                    throw new TypeError("can't convert " + this + ' to object');
                }
                var str = '' + this;
                count = +count;
                if (count != count) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                if (count < 0) {
                    throw new RangeError('repeat count must be non-negative');
                }
                if (count == Infinity) {
                    throw new RangeError('repeat count must be less than infinity');
                }
                count = Math.floor(count);
                if (str.length == 0 || count == 0) {
                    return '';
                }
                if (str.length * count >= 1 << 28) {
                    throw new RangeError('repeat count must not overflow maximum string size');
                }
                var rpt = '';
                for (;;) {
                    if ((count & 1) == 1) {
                        rpt += str;
                    }
                    count >>>= 1;
                    if (count == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    str += str;
                }
                return rpt;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * String.padStart()
     * version 1.0.1
     */
    if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
        Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'padStart', {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: function(targetLength, padString) {
                targetLength = targetLength >> 0; //floor if number or convert non-number to 0;
                padString = (typeof padString !== 'undefined') ? padString : ' ';
                if (this.length > targetLength) {
                    return String(this);
                } else {
                    targetLength = targetLength - this.length;
                    if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                        padString += padString.repeat(targetLength / padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
                    }
                    return padString.slice(0, targetLength) + String(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * String.padEnd()
     * version 1.0.1
     */
    if (!String.prototype.padEnd) {
        Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'padEnd', {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: function(targetLength, padString) {
                targetLength = targetLength >> 0; //floor if number or convert non-number to 0;
                padString = (typeof padString !== 'undefined') ? padString : ' ';
                if (this.length > targetLength) {
                    return String(this);
                } else {
                    targetLength = targetLength - this.length;
                    if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                        padString += padString.repeat(targetLength / padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
                    }
                    return String(this) + padString.slice(0, targetLength);
                }
            }
        });
    }




    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////           ////////////////////////////// 
    //////////////////////////////    END    ////////////////////////////// 
    //////////////////////////////           ////////////////////////////// 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




    try {


        var a = [
            { a: 5, b: 164, r: 80 },
            { a: 151, b: 31, r: -2147483648 },
            { a: -143, b: 223, r: -2147483648 },
            { a: -190, b: 430, r: -3112960 },
            { a: -474, b: 472, r: 637534208 },
            { a: 1073741824, b: 1, r: -2147483648 },
            { a: 1073741824, b: 2, r: 0 },
            { a: 5, b: 3, r: 40 },
            { a: -1, b: 1, r: -2 }

        ];


        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            v = a[i]
            var rr = util.leftShift(v.a, v.b);
            Write(v.a + ' << ' + v.b + ' == ' + v.r + '(' + rr + ') | ' + (rr == v.r)+'<br/>');
        }

    } catch (e) {
        Write(Stringify(e))
    }
</script>
```